# How to skip NULL values from MySQL CONCAT and GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql

I have this query that returns the name of the product and the array of images as a JSON string. However, when there is no image attached to a product, I would like this query to return an empty array for the `images` property.

Currently, it returns this when there is no product image found:

```
{ "name": "Product Name", "images": [{"id": null, "slug": null}]}
```

I tried to add an IF condition into the CONCAT method, but it returns the same response.

```
SELECT p.name,
CONCAT('[',
          IF(i.id = NULL,
            '',
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (
              JSON_OBJECT(
                'id', i.id, 
                'slug', i.slug
              )
            ))
          ),
       ']') AS images
FROM products AS p
        LEFT JOIN _product_images AS pi ON pi.pId = p.id
        LEFT JOIN images AS i ON i.id = pi.iId
WHERE p.id = 4;
```

Thank you!

Comment: How can an id be null?

Comment: @Strawberry With a LEFT JOIN

Comment: But doesn't GC ignore NULLs anyway under those circumstances?

Comment: GC gets a valid JSON from `JSON_OBJECT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IF(i.id = NULL, ...)` returns `NULL`, for whatever value has i.id (even `NULL`), which is a falsy value.

You want to use instead `IF (i.id IS NULL, ...)`

From [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html) :

> You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as =, <, or <> to test for NULL. To demonstrate this for yourself, try the following query:
>
> ```sql
> mysql> SELECT 1 = NULL, 1 <> NULL, 1 < NULL, 1 > NULL;  
> +----------+-----------+----------+----------+  
> | 1 = NULL | 1 <> NULL | 1 < NULL | 1 > NULL |  
> +----------+-----------+----------+----------+  
> |     NULL |      NULL |     NULL |     NULL |  
> +----------+-----------+----------+----------+
> ```

Answer (score 5):

As other have mentioned, `i.id = NULL` will always evaluate to `NULL`. But your approach is needlessly complicated and would raise an error on a strictly configured server. On db-fiddle I get the following error:

> ER_MIX_OF_GROUP_FUNC_AND_FIELDS: In aggregated query without GROUP BY,
>   expression #2 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column
>   'test.i.id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

[demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oBeozuwVtArjoqxmYY1nTv/0)

So the check `i.id IS NULL` needs to be done within the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function:

```
SELECT p.name,
CONCAT('[',
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (
    IF (i.id IS NULL, '',
      JSON_OBJECT(
        'id', i.id, 
        'slug', i.slug
       )
    )
   )),
']') AS images
FROM products AS p
        LEFT JOIN _product_images AS pi ON pi.pId = p.id
        LEFT JOIN images AS i ON i.id = pi.iId
WHERE p.id = 4
```

However - You can avoid the check, when you use an INNER JOIN. But the INNER JOIN will also ignore the data from the `products` table - So I would do that JOIN in a correlated subquery. An finally you can use `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` to generate a JSON array.

[demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5F7wXJXY98yy4rbgVrvv4y/0)

```
SELECT p.name, COALESCE((
  SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(
    'id', i.id, 
    'slug', i.slug
  ))
  FROM _product_images AS pi 
  JOIN images AS i ON i.id = pi.iId
  WHERE pi.pId = p.id
), JSON_ARRAY()) AS images
FROM products AS p
#WHERE p.id = 4;
```

[demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nCgZZPtaamTssrdmC6odwv/0)

Comment: Thank you @paul-spiegel, your JSON_ARRAYAGG() approach to generate a JSON array is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `IS NULL` to check for a `NULL` value:

```
SELECT
    p.name,
    CONCAT('[',
      GROUP_CONCAT(
        IF(id IS NULL,
           '',
           DISTINCT JSON_OBJECT('id', i.id, 'slug', i.slug))),
        ']') AS images
FROM products AS p
LEFT JOIN _product_images AS pi ON pi.pId = p.id
LEFT JOIN images AS i ON i.id = pi.iId
WHERE p.id = 4
GROUP BY p.name;
```

As a side note, `DISTINCT` is not a function, and you should not be using it as such, so I removed the function parentheses which you were using.

**Edit:** Updated SQL to satisfy the group restrictions. The IF-Statement for checking i.id outside of the GROUP_CONCAT would fail, due to multiple image items per row.

Comment: You are trying to access `i.id` outside of a GROUP function, while it is not in the GROUP BY or WHERE clauses.